# Как правильно оборвать соединение TcpClient

Tags: c#

В клиентском ПО в отдельном потоке идет работа с сервером. Программа в отдельном `Task` отправляет файл и ждет пока сервер обработает и пришлет ответ. Если пользователь хочет закрыть соединение `tcpClient.Close()` то в `Task` выбросится исключение. Как корректно в данной ситуации закрывать соединение?

Comment: Привидите пример кода, простое закрытие Socket\TcpClient - не выдает исключение (если конечно объект инициализирован).

Comment: @Alexis Ошибка не на закрытии, а при обрашениии к TcpClient в потоке после закрытия его в главном потоке приложения. Меня интересует алгоритм как закрыть правильно и оборвать соединение что б сервер откатил транзакцию

Comment: CancellationToken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не дело подставлять подножку своему коду, убивая объект, с которым другой поток ведёт работу. Передайте сигнал о необходимости окончания работы в работающий `Task` (например, через `CancellationToken`), и пусть этот `Task` сам закроет свой `TcpClient`.